# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET: The connection was reset when uploading a large file

Tags: asp.net, iis, maxrequestlength

I had a mysterious error where a file greater than 4MB generated a random error. Later on I realized it was caused due to the [http `maxrequestlength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)
. An image cannot be greater than 4MB when uploaded by default.

I know that this can change from the web.config file.

When I tried to cater for this error, by displaying another page, a different error started popping up. When debugging, the program enters application_error immediately.

When executing `Server.GetLastError()` Exception generated:

> [System.Web.HttpUnhandledException] {"Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was
>   thrown."} System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>
> the stack trace: at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   ASP.businessprofile_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Users\Mattew\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\4ea30077\8f66786f\App_Web_h5fmhavk.4.cs:line 0 at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

If I try any code inside the application_error method, e.g. redirecting, still the error page:
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
is displayed.

Questions

1. How should this error be handled? Can it be handled before hand? So this error is not displayed? ( I tried using jquery to get the file size before and check it but I'm finding it too complex
2. If Question 1 is not 'answerable', is there a way to intercept this error and display a friendly error?

Comment: That looks like an IIS limit.

Comment: What does that mean exactly please? is it a problem from my code or from the IIS? I don't think I even use IIS, since i just hit run on Visual Studio and a temporary server is started!

Comment: You mean you're using Cassini.  I'm not sure.  What's the inner exception?

Comment: Sry I dont know what Cassini is :/
Inner Exception: Maximum Requested Length Exceeded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this out.

Under system web in web.config

add this line..

```
  <system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
```

Then you need to check the file size

```
if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string Extension = Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/xl/" + FileName);
            double filesize = (double)AsyncFileUpload1.FileBytes.Length;
            if (filesize < 106496)
            {
               //do something
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("File size must be less than 2MB.");
            }
```

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know..

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will try and use it now. after more debugging, I can add the following information:


-  Response.Headers

 'Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection {System.PlatformNotSupportedException}

when I open it,
the relevant message I found was "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it does work since the maxRequestlength is very big. I did research this. but still, if a user places something greater than the maxRequestLength, what will happen (although this is very rare to happen), it is still like 'cheating' from the developer's side. isn't there a neater way to do this? 

PS I do not use async file upload, should I use that instead?

Comment: With the approach suggested by @AnandMohanAwasthi is actually a waste of resources. You let the user upload a huge file and then at the server you reject it because it is larger than your lower limit you have in code. I am myself searching for a better solution, but strongly feel the suggested solution is a wrong solution.