# Debugging Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) on asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I am developing a new site in asp.net (c#) and sometimes I get an Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) in Chrome. If I then open "Tools" in Chrome and clear the browsing data and reload the page, everything seems to work again. I experience this error from time to time but have not been able to identify why I am getting the error nor a pattern.

I have tried setting customErrors=off but the errorpage is never shown.

Any help on how to debug the error is much appreciated!

thanks
Thomas

Comment: you are run out of resource, maybe too many tcp ip opens, maybe you forget to close handlers, or even maybe your network software (drivers or something) is unstable, for example you have drop out from the network, or even if you have router/modem disconnections from the net

Comment: I run everything on localhost (client, iis and sqlserver). Would the running out of ressoures etc be on the client, iis or sqlserver and is there somewhere where I can find additional info on the problem (logs etc)? I tried looking in the event viewer (win7) but could not find anything

Comment: The connection reset is on your client.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to find any information on what is causing it? You wrote some suggestions above, but it seems like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Start from check if you have internet connection drop down, by monitor your modem. Tell me if you have.

Comment: Hi, since everything is running on the same computer (browser, webserver and dbserver) and my code does not depend on anything not on the computer, there is no ingoing/outgoing network traffic.

Comment: if the network have problems is close and is not working nether the one on the computer. The network is a program - if reset, or change or close is stop working to your computer too.

Comment: Turned out to be my antivirus-program. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be my antivirus-programme

Answer (score 0):

This solution working fine in my code..

Add below code in **web.config** file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
</system.web>
```

Refer from : [ERR_CONNECTION_RESET: The connection was reset when uploading a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129362/err-connection-reset-the-connection-was-reset-when-uploading-a-large-file)